# Запрос UPDATE при 10М записей

Tags: php, mysql, php7

Доброе утро!
Есть бд, в которой 10М строк, Myisam, при чтении никаких проблем и тд нет, проблема начинается когда запрос UPDATE, таблица просто зависает и UPDATE происходит 1 в секунду, а то и две.

Прочитал что лучше перейти на innodb и перейти на INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY.

Подскажите, что в данном случае лучше делать?

Спасибо!

Comment: С такими "подробностями" особенного ничего ждать не следует. Где структура, какие индексы (если есть вообще), что обновляет ваш update по отношению к структуре базы/таблицы? Какие записи в slow log? По сколько зараз идёт в коммит? Где база крутится, какая конфигурация, версия

Comment: Индексов нет. В таблице 15 колонок, запрос обновляет 13 колонок. VDS: 1 Intel CPU, 1GB RAM, 25GB SSD. Версия MySQL 5. Извините что не сказал сразу подробности, спасибо за замечание.

Comment: *В таблице 15 колонок, запрос обновляет 13 колонок.* Ну в таком супе вообще лучше подумать о применимости REPLACE INTO...